# has one and belongs to with joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a UserType and User models. The association is the following;

```
UserType
has_one :user

User
belongs_to user_type
```

I am trying to get the users where its user_type name is X.

I have tried;

```
User.joins(:user_type).where(:user_type => {name: 'X'}).all
```

it gives error.

```
 `require'
    from /app/bin/rails:8:in `<main>'irb(main):015:0> User.joins(:user_type).where(:user_type => {name: 'normal'}).all
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "user_type"
LINE 1: ...sers" ON "user_types"."id" = "users"."user_type_id" WHERE "user_type"."u...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_types" ON "user_types"."id" = "users"."user_type_id" WHERE "user_type"."name" = $1
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "user_type"
LINE 1: ...sers" ON "user_types"."id" = "users"."user_type_id" WHERE "user_type"."u...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_types" ON "user_types"."id" = "users"."user_type_id" WHERE "user_type"."name" = $1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "user_type"
LINE 1: ...sers" ON "user_types"."id" = "users"."user_type_id" WHERE "user_type"."u...
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the error with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure your association setting is correct

You need to add a colon before `user_type`

```
User
belongs_to :user_type
```

And you should use `table name` on the join query.

By default, user_type's table name is `user_types`

```
User.joins(:user_type).where(:user_types => {name: 'X'}).all
```

And if you want to avoid the n+1 problem you should use `includes`

```
User.includes(:user_type).where(:user_types => {name: 'X'}).all
```

Comment: The missing part was `By default, user_type's table name is user_types`